# Error Saving Custom Table: Specified Cast Is Not Valid

Tags: sql, acumatica

I have a custom DAC, 'BranchPaymentDefault.' One of the fields is a lookup to the 'Account' object.

Whenever I open the page, or try to use the selector to select an Account, I get an error saying 'Specified Cast Not Valid

I tried using the PXSelector attribute instead of Account attribute, but I get the same error.

DAC

```
namespace VendorMasterPaymentDefaults
{
```

[Serializable]
  public class BranchPaymentDefault : IBqlTable
  {

```
[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Branch")]
[Branch()]
public virtual Int32? BranchID { get; set; }
public abstract class branchID : IBqlField { }

[PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
[PXDefault(typeof(Vendor.bAccountID))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor")] 
[PXParent(typeof(Select<Vendor, Where<Vendor.bAccountID, Equal<Current<BranchPaymentDefault.vendorID>>>>))]
public virtual Int32? VendorID { get; set; }
public abstract class vendorID : IBqlField {  }  

[Account(typeof(Account.accountID), IsKey = false, DisplayName = "Account")]
public virtual int? AccountID { get; set; }
public abstract class accountID : IBqlField { }

[PXDBDecimal]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allotment Amt")]
public virtual decimal? AllotmentAmt { get; set; } 
public abstract class allotmentAmt : IBqlField { }  

[PXDBString(IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allotment Type")]
[PXDefault(allotmentType.Values.Percentage)]
[PXStringList(new string[]{ allotmentType.Values.Percentage, allotmentType.Values.FixedAmt },
              new string[]{ allotmentType.Values.UI.Percentage, allotmentType.Values.UI.FixedAmt })]
public virtual string AllotmentType { get; set; }
public abstract class allotmentType : IBqlField 
{
   public class Values
   {
     public const string Percentage = "PCT";
     public const string FixedAmt = "FIX";

     public class UI
     {
        public const string Percentage = "Percent";
        public const string FixedAmt = "Fixed"; 
     }
   }       
}


[PXDBCreatedByID()] 
public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }    
public abstract class createdByID : IBqlField { } 

[PXDBCreatedDateTime]  
public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; } 
public abstract class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }

[PXDBLastModifiedByID] 
public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
public abstract class lastModifiedByID : IBqlField { } 

[PXDBLastModifiedDateTime]
public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : IBqlField { }
```

}
}

GRAPH

```
namespace PX.Objects.AP
{
 public class VendorMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<VendorMaint>
 {


public PXSelect<BranchPaymentDefault, 
Where<BranchPaymentDefault.vendorID, 
Equal<Current<BAccount.bAccountID>>>> BranchPaymentDefaults;


  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the SQL Table's declaration to the question?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BranchPaymentDefault](
 [BranchID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [VendorID] [int] NOT NULL,
 [AllotmentAmt] [decimal](18, 0) NOT NULL,
 [AllotmentType] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
 [CreatedByID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [CreatedDateTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 [LastModifiedByID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
 [LastModifiedDateTime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
 [AccountID] [int] NOT NULL
)

Comment: I tried using the following attributes for the Account ID Field..

    [PXDefault]
    [Account(
      null, 
      typeof(Search<Account.accountID, Where<Match<Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>), 
      DisplayName = "Account", 
      DescriptionField = typeof(Account.description), 
      Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
    [PXRestrictor(typeof(Where<Account.type, Equal<AccountType.expense>>), PX.Objects.GL.Messages.YTDNetIncomeMayBeLiability)]  
    public virtual Int32? AccountID{ get; set; }
    public abstract class accountID: PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<accountID> { }

Comment: Usually "Specified cast is not valid" error means that you have specified different data types for the field in the Selector/Field Declaration/Database. Try to removing the selector at all and working with the raw field. If that works, then we need to understand the exact problem with selector, otherwise, there is a problem either in DAC or Database Table.

Comment: I removed the [Account] attribute, and I still get the error. The DB type of AccountID is INT, and I'm using Int32 in my DAC.

Comment: Can you place `[PXDBInt, PXUIField(DisplayName="Account")]` to the property and try to work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually with the BranchAttribute. For some reason, using the parameterless constructor was throwing the exception.